# Get custom field in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables

Signers:

```
CREATE TABLE signers (idSigner INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name TEXT, idNumber TEXT, rol TEXT)
```

and signatures:

```
CREATE TABLE signatures (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, documentId text, page INTEGER, coords TEXT, date TEXT, content TEXT, image TEXT, idSigner TEXT)
```

I want a select, that returns all the signers, and a custom column, with a true value, if the idSigner exists in the signatures table, and a false if not.

I have tryied with INNER JOINS, but I haven't achieved anything.

Expected result

```
idSigner           name      signed
1234               name1     true
2345               name2     false
3456               name3     false
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show what you've tried, and what the result was? Also, what's the relationship between the tables? Which field corresponds to which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether a row exists, use EXISTS:

```
SELECT idSigner,
       name,
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM signatures
               WHERE idSigner = signers.idSigner
              ) AS signed
FROM signers;
```